# Making Teamcity clone a git repository

Tags: git, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have a build process that relies on git-describe so I want TeamCity to clone the repository instead of only putting the source without git into the /work folder.

I'm using the JetBrains Git plugin, is there another plugin that does that or should I just write another script that does a git clone before doing a build?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is pre-Jetbrains plugin, which supports checkout on agent: http://www.knowledgetree.com/blog/continuous-integration-with-teamcity-git

Comment: I think it should be possible to combine these plugins (take checkout on agent part from the old one).

Comment: Thanks. it worked.
Also blogged about it here: http://www.tigraine.at/2009/10/27/setting-up-teamcity-git-psake-for-dotless/

Answer (score 1):

TeamCity 5.1.1 and up supports this with its default git plugin ([info](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/TeamCity+5.1.1+Release+Notes))